# Java Null pointer Exception from string iterator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hi I am getting a null pointer exception on the line g.getid(id1) and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Iterator<String> it1 = players1.iterator();
Iterator<String> it2 = players2.iterator();
while (it1.hasNext()&&it2.hasNext()) {
    String id1 = it1.next();
    g.getID(id1); //NULL point exception?  :(

    //g.getId finds the player with the unique ID.
    String id2 = it2.next();
    g.getID(id2); //NULL referance exception? :(
}
```

My objective is to get the string from the list that makes up the iterator of players1 and player2 and reference is in the g.getId(id1); and g.getId(id2); as it goes through the loop each ID is different.

g is a referance of the game class.

protected Game g; 
In the game class the method for getId is as followed
 T getID(String id);

Comment: Its references a class with many methods etc. I've added it as protected Game g;

Comment: Can you show the code where it is assigned/initialized? That's likely where your problem is.

Comment: Its assigned in this class as protected Game g;

In the game class its
<T extends Player> T getID(String id);

Comment: That's not where it's assigned/initialized. That's where it's declared. I'm looking for something like `g = new Game()` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that `g == null` - have you attempted using the debugger? Or perhaps just `System.out.println(g)` before the loop?

**Edit**: looking at what you edited, it is DEFINITELY the case that g is null. Simply writing `protected Game g` only creates a "Game-shaped" variable that *could* hole an instance of Game if you put one there. There will only be a null in there though until you do this:

```
g = new Game();    // potentially, Game() takes some arguments too.
```

Comment: g referances a class called Game. I didn't write the methods in Game though/ I'm just adapting the code to meet my scope. GetID is a method in game.

Comment: Nevertheless, it appears likely that you didn't instantiate g correctly. Did you try logging it like I recommended?

Comment: Ahh yessss! I think i worked it out. I had the g = new game wrapped in the main class. I've moved the method in and its working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

then need more information, add your full code, or may be try

Game g = new Game();

Comment: No g is a referance to Game, which is a class with many methods. i didn't write Game. 
Game is rerferances in this class as 
Protected Game g; 
I'm assuming thats where the null is coming from though.

Comment: Just writing Protected Game g won't work. May be try to instantiate it as shown.